# How to get data from dynamically created EditText and TextView inside a linearlayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

In my main.xml I have a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearMain"
        >
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, inside my Main.java I am retrieving values from the DB (name and price of an item). Then, I dynamically created my form using the below code:

```
 Cursor cursor = mydb.getAllJuice();

 lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);

 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int cid = cursor.getInt(0);
            String id = Integer.toString(cid);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String price = cursor.getString(2);

            // Create LinearLayout
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            // Create TextView
            TextView product = new TextView(this);
            product.setText(name+"    ");
            ll.addView(product);

            // Create TextView
            TextView pricetxt = new TextView(this);
            pricetxt.setText("      "+price);
            ll.addView(pricetxt);

            // Create TextView
            TextView currency = new TextView(this);
            currency.setText("  LL      ");
            ll.addView(currency);

            // Create TextView
            TextView qtylabel = new TextView(this);
            qtylabel.setText("QTY      ");
            ll.addView(qtylabel);

            EditText qty = new EditText(this);
            qty.setMinLines(1);
            qty.setMaxLines(3);
            ll.addView(qty);
            lm.addView(ll);

        }

        // Create LinearLayout
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);



        final Button btn = new Button(this);
        // Give button an ID
        int j = 122;
        btn.setId(j+1);
        btn.setText("Add To Cart");
        // set the layoutParams on the button
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
        //Add button to LinearLayout
        ll.addView(btn);
        //Add button to LinearLayout defined in XML
        lm.addView(ll);
```

The user will be able to enter the number of items and consequently onClick of the button a TextView will be manipulated.

To fill this textview I will need to loop on all the items that were created to check the price and check how the number that the user entered. I tried using the below code, however I am not able to access the specific item that I want as I have in each row 2 TextView and 1 editText:

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // code will be here
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        total = 0 ;

                        View v1 = null;
                        for(int i=0; i<lm.getChildCount(); i++) {
                            v1 = lm.getChildAt(i);


                        }


                    }
                });
```

How can I access the different element in the v1?

Comment: Looks like you could use the ViewHolder pattern

Comment: Are you sure you can't use RecyclerView for your usecase?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tag parameter of your Views (TextView, EditText etc.): setTag(Object) . Tags are essentially an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate structure. Check Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) for more details.

P.S. Instead to use your approach, you can use RecyclerView (or older ListView) with ViewHolder. This already mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question:
The problem is that your "product", "pricetxt", "btn" variables are local variables and gets garbage collected after your current loop iteration is over.

Well you can implement view holder pattern in your project.

Create a class named ViewHolder

```
  class ViewHolder{

  LinearLayout ll;
  TextView product;
  TextView pricetxt ;
  TextView currency ;
  TextView qtylabel ;
  EditText qty ;}
  public ViewHolder(LinearLayout ll TextView product TextView pricetxt TextView currency TextView qtylabel EditText qty)
  {
    this.l1= l1;
    this.product=product;
    this.pricetxt=pricetxt;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.qtylabel = qtylevel;
    this.qty = qty;

  }
```

This class can hold all your data by passing all these parameters (qty, pricetxt, etc).
Now you have to maintain a List for this ViewHolder Object at the top. You can do this as-

```
  List myList<ViewHolder> = new ArrayList<ViewHolder>();
```

At the end of every iteration, create and add the ViewHolder object;
You can do this as follows

```
  ViewHolder currentView = new ViewHolder(l1.product,pricetxt,currency,qtylabel,qty);
```

myList.add(currentView);
        myList.add(currentView);

You can access any ViewHolder object maintained inside the list at position "index" as

```
    myList.get(index);
```

Or the EditText "qty" as

```
     myList.get(index).qty;
```

In this way you can access your created EditTexts and TextView even after the loop iteration is over.

My Suggestion:- No one does it in this way. As suggested some guys over here you should you android implement recommended [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) which is much more efficient than the current implementation. In cases you can even you [ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).